# Can someone explain me the following terms in connected app, Salesforce?

Tags: connected-apps

I am having following questions related to Salesforce connected apps.

1. What does it mean by external apps in Salesforce? Is it 3 party apps
   available in App Exchange? Or totally SF independent web
   applications developed using other technologies like Java, Node JS?
   Or 3rd party Android, ios mobile applicaion?
2. Say for example I am writing Apex class to expose Rest service. And
   I want to call this service from my Java program. Do I have to
   configure my Java application using connected apps? Or can I
   directly call the service?
3. A Sales employee logs in to their Salesforce org and opens the Your
   Benefits web app. Salesforce sends a SAML response to the service
   provider, which you defined when configuring the connected app. The
   service provider identifies the user, and validates the digital
   signature sent by Salesforce in the SAML response. The user is
   logged in to the Your Benefits web app.

   In the above given statement what do they mean by 'Your Benefits web
   app'? Is that an external web app developed using other technologies
   like Java, Node JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**External apps**

External is basically anything that is off-platform - mobile app, off-platform web-app, service on AWS or Google cloud, Apple Watch app sending your pulse to Salesforce to track customer satisfaction. It can actually even be another Salesforce org

**Calling webservices**

Generally, yes. Anyone who's using Salesforce need to be logged in. And that is what connected apps are used for. However, there's a way to expose your web service without auth using sites. In this case web service users will basically use guest user profile.

**Your Benefits web app**

You explained that yourself. That's exactly what you said - an external web app developed off-platform

Comment: Thank you. Now, I got better understanding about the terms and also I have practiced connected apps with curl. Now, my doubts are clear.